# Pivotal Web Services and Kafka service

Tags: apache-kafka, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I have registered in Pivotal Web Services and do not see the Kafka service there. Is it available for a free trial plan ? How to use Kafka message broker with Pivotal Web Services?

Comment: You could deploy and register your own service broker (space-scoped). E.g this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015140/pivotal-web-services-and-kafka-service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of me writing this, there is no Kafka service in the Pivotal Web Services marketplace. You can see the list of services that are publicly available here.

https://docs.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/services/

If you want to use Kafka with your apps, you'd need to bring your own service or use a third party service provider that's outside of the marketplace.

https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Am-I-restricted-to-using-service-providers-that-are-in-the-Marketplace